# Gracias por el apoyo

Tags: python

Se necesita un programa que sea capaz de calcular los descuentos en el área de ventas de
una empresa de retail.
Un usuario deberá cargar los precios de los productos en el programa, la cantidad de precios
que cargará es indeterminada. Por lo tanto, se ha decidido que la carga finalizará al ingresar
el precio CERO.
Una vez que se cuente con el total de la operación de venta, se podrán aplicar descuentos
dependiendo del monto alcanzado:

Si el monto de la sumatoria de los precios es inferior a $ 50.000, entonces el descuento será del
7% sobre el total.
Si el monto de la sumatoria de los precios alcanza o sobrepasa los $ 50.000, entonces el
descuento aplicado debe ser del 12%.
La salida que se espera por pantalla corresponde a:
• La sumatoria de todos los precios ingresados (total de la venta sin descuentos)
• El monto de descuento logrado.
• El monto a pagar (con los descuentos aplicados)

---

lo estoy haciendo así, pero no me da resultado, en elif si me da resultado correcto pero no en el if

compra = float (input ("ingrese el monto de la compra: "))

if compra <= 50000:
compra -= compra * 0.7
print (" el total de su compra es de $", compra)

elif compra >= 50001:
compra -= compra * 0.12
print ("el total de su compra es de $" ,compra)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yo lo haria de la siguiente manera.

Primero me comentaste que el precio cuando llegue a 0 finalizara por lo tanto empezamos declarando las variables

```
# Variables
precio = 1
suma_total = 0

# Realizamos un ciclo while hasta que el precio ingresado sea 0
while precio != 0:
    precio = float(input('Ingrese el Precio de los Productos: '))
    suma_total += precio

# Calculamos el monto de descuento segun la suma total de los productos que se han ingresado despues de que el ingresado haya sido 0
if suma_total < 50001:
     # Para el 7%
     descuento = suma_total * 0.07
else:
    # Para el 12%
    descuento = suma_total * 0.12


# Calcular el monto a pagar con el descuento aplicado segun el precio
monto_a_pagar = suma_total - descuento

# Mostramos los resultados
print(f'La sumatoria de todos los precios es: ${suma_total:.2f}')
print(f'El monto del descuento es: ${descuento:.2f}')
print(f'El monto a pagar es: ${monto_a_pagar:.2f}')
```

Es importante que entiendas el apartado donde se muestran los resultados.
Se utiliza esa sintaxis para especificar que el valor insertado sera con un formato de dos digitos decimales despues del punto decimal. Si quieres puedes modificarlo segun tus nesecidades.

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: No es recomendable responder preguntas mal planteadas, incompletas o confusas. Es probable que tu respuesta no sea lo que busca el OP, y en cualquier caso terminara cerrada.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me quedo muy clara tú respuesta, me ayudaste un monton. -